# Android webview: difference between Samsung Note 2 and Nexus 5 ?

Tags: android, css, webview

I am loading an HTML file into a webview with:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/WebViewContent/extraHelp/help.html");
```

This works fine on my Samsung Note 2, but does not work on my Nexus 5. On the Nexus 5 I get an error message related to the fonts.

```
Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/WebViewContent/extraHelp/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff
Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/WebViewContent/extraHelp/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf
```

I would expect the two devices to be able to find these fonts in the browser. The relevant CSS code is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
    src: url(OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot);
    src: url(OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
         url(OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'),
         url(OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#OpenSansRegular) format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the http://developer.android.com

**[Migrating to WebView in Android 4.4](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)**

Android 4.4 (API level 19) introduces a new version of WebView that is based on Chromium. This change upgrades WebView performance and standards support for HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript to match the latest web browsers. Any apps using WebView will inherit these upgrades when running on Android 4.4 and higher.

Comment: I figured the difference is between 4.3 and 4.4 so how do I change my code to support Chromium?

Comment: Try changing your TargetSdk version in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: My target is already set to 17. I think it still picks up the latest webview.

Comment: That didn't help. It seems Chromium is missing those fonts.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was not related to the fonts, but to the android version. Upgrading the phone from 4.4 to 4.4.2 fixed the problem.